# IIS 8.5 throwing 404.3 errors for ASPX pages

Tags: asp.net, iis

I just installed IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1. I installed it after installing Visual Studio 12 and the 4.5 version of the .NET framework. I created a new site and now I am getting this error:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration.

I have seen posts here and elsewhere regarding this error and none of the fixes have worked. I have tried running aspnet_regiis.exe - the correct 64 bit version. I have also installed all the ASP.NET development tools, including the .BET 4.5 Extensibility feature. Still I am getting this error. I haven't found a post yet with a fix I have not tried.

Has anyone fixed this issue a different way?

Answer (score 13):

I know that this question is old but I've managed to solve this issue on Windows Server 2012 without reinstalling anything, so just in case I leave my solution for future reference:

I just went to 'Add roles and features' and in the Features part I checked 'HTTP activation' on '.Net Framework 4.5 Features->WCF Services'.

Comment: This also works on Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer could be improved if it referenced where the 'Add Roles and Features' thing was selected.  I have clicked all over IIS Manager and can't find anything that looks like that.

Comment: Worked for me also in Windows 10, IIS 10.  If you're trying to locate where this setting is found:  Control Panel -> Programs and Features; Turn Windows Features On or Off; .NET Framework 4.x Advanced Services -> WCF Services -> HTTP Activation.  (Obviously the version of .NET Framework may vary.)

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be quite simple. I removed IIS completely, rebooted, and installed it again, making sure to include all the Asp.NET development features the second time.

I think that's where I went wrong the first time. I installed IIS without those features and tried to add them in later. It seems like that should work, but it didn't. The total re installation did, though.

Answer (score 0):

`404.3` is the MIME type restriction, it means the server is not serving files with an .aspx extension. That's okay, it is not suppose to. But it has to be defined under the `Handler Mappings` like this:

[image]

If there entries are not there, add them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, those entries aren't there. However, I'm not able to add them either. The System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory isn't available, and when I try to add the Isapi handler I get an error saying the IsapiModole or the CgiModule must be in the modules list. IT's frustrating because I thought this is what aspnet_regiis.exe was supposed to do. It's also amazing how much trouble was caused by installing IIS after the .NET framework. I may have to do something drastic like uninstall everything and start over.

Answer (score 0):

On IIS 8.5, Open Server Manager, navigate to the Server Roles screen Scroll down the list to the "Web Server (IIS)" --> "Web Server" and check all the options under "Application Development". That should work!