# How to quickly host a .aspx file locally?

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost, iis-express

I have an aspx file that is all inclusive. Everything it needs to do is coded in the aspx file itself. I have no other files.

How do I quickly host this locally to test it? I have IIS installed and IIS express bu can't figure out how to host the aspx file without the web browser simply reading the contents of the file or giving me a 404.3 error.

I just want to pop open the file like you'd do for any other html page.

Edit this was the solution, but for ASP 4.7: [IIS 8.5 throwing 404.3 errors for ASPX pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283420/iis-8-5-throwing-404-3-errors-for-aspx-pages/37478581)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not asking how to install or open IIS. I'm asking how to host the aspx file outside of the visual studio IDE.

Comment: This was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283420/iis-8-5-throwing-404-3-errors-for-aspx-pages/37478581

Comment: This is out-side visual studio - IIS is a web server that can host your aspx files. Just setup it correctly, and place there your file - IIS is not the web server that comes with visual studio for tests

Comment: now, to read the file locally from IIS, just type on your url `localhost`  and you see the default site